# Figures of speech in "Once Upon a Time" by Gabriel Okara

Tags: poetry, literary-device, gabriel-okara

Here are two extracts from the poem "[Once Upon a Time](https://books.google.co.uk/books?id=GYCTCwAAQBAJ&pg=PT27)" by Gabriel Imomotimi Okara:

> ‘Feel at home!’ ‘Come again’:
> they say, and when I come
> again and feel
> at home, once, twice,
> there will be no thrice—
> for then I find doors shut on me.

> I have also learned to say,’Goodbye’,
> when I mean ‘Good-riddance’:
> to say ‘Glad to meet you’,
> without being glad; and to say ‘It’s been
> nice talking to you’, after being bored.

Are there any figures of speech in these extracts, and if so, what are they?